# Contest Proposal: Close out entries from inactive users

Tags: discussion

**Proposal:** Remove entries from users who are not active on this site, starting with entries from users that have been inactive the longest.

**Rationale:** A major problem with the photo contest is the only way to remove an entry from the list is for it to "win". With over 450 entries, it can run for 8-9 years with minimal involvement. With an expected wait time of about 4 years, there's little incentive for new participants.

Further, "winners" may not have been active on the site for years by the time their photos are featured. The current winner, for instance, was "Last seen Aug 9 '17 at 14:20".

Answer (score 4):

This probably isn't a bad suggestion since they won't actually see the result of their effort.  Alternately, it might be worth pinging users when their photo does rise to the top as a means of trying to re-engage users that have stopped participating.  Either option seems decent.

Comment: I like the idea of notifying the winners when their photo is featured, if that's not too technically challenging. Even if they are relatively active on the site, people sometimes go on holiday or take short breaks from visiting, and might not realise they had been featured.

Comment: @kat I suspect we'd implement it by super pinging in the chat room.  Mods can ping so that it sends a notification even if people haven't used chat before.